# How to close the Ng-Zorro menu after user click on menu-item or outside the menu?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

How to close the Ng-Zorro menu after user click on menu-item or outside the menu?

https://ng.ant.design/components/menu/en#components-menu-demo-horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property `nzInlineCollapsed` is responsible for displaying and hiding menu, so if you bind menu click event with this `nzInlineCollapsed` it will then it will hide if the property with which it is binded is false. Here `isCollapsed` is binded with `nzInlineCollapsed` so it on button click `isCollapsed` is turned false then your menu will hide.

```
<ul nz-menu nzMode="inline" [nzInlineCollapsed]="isCollapsed">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap it with ngIf and set a state on it.
If users clicks an Menu-Item, you can just set the variable to false, so the menu will be hidden. Same goes for clicks outside the menu, you just need an event listener for it.
Made it like this: `<div *ngIf="show == true">`. Then just set show to false, if user clicks an item, or outside the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just use nz-menu-item on li

Ex: `<li nz-menu-item> Item </li>`